# React Router renders the target page on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
export const Bar = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes.barWrapper}>
        {
          props.releaseData.map((item, idx) => {
            return (
              <Router>
                <Link className={classes.link} to={`/version/${item.id}`}><BarComponent/></Link>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/version/:id" children={<VersionPage />} />
                </Switch>
              </Router>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I have a component that renders multiple bars, which is clickable and has links to a child component called `VersionPage`.

```
export const VersionPage = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { releaseTitle } = props
  let { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h3}>{id}</h3>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

In the child component, I use `useParams()` to render the `id` passed in through the URL. However, the problem is that it does not redirect the user to the new page `/release/:id`, but it renders this `VersionComponent` on the same page.

How can I make it redirect to a new page with the `id` passed in?

Comment: you should not wrap the Router in a map, React apps are single page and you should use the router to show/hide pages based on url and params.

Answer (score 0):

This will open the page in new Tab

```
<Link target='_blank' className={classes.link} to={`/version/${item.id}`}><BarComponent/></Link>
```